# How do I set the inital pose of a robot in gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, pose, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I've created my own world file that has:

This normally spawns the robot at x=0, y=0.

How could I spawn it somewhere else, say x=1, y=1?

I know I could spawn the robot and then move it by calling the service: set_model_state, but I've found doing this with the pr2 doesn't work very well with other objects in the world.

pr2_no_controllers has an arg called 'optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE.'  How do I get at this from my world file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40627/how-do-i-set-the-inital-pose-of-a-robot-in-gazebo?/) by [EmbeddedSystem](https://answers.ros.org/users/2926/embeddedsystem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-07-10**:
If you came to this thread trying to set an initial joint configuration of the robot, check this thread too: https://answers.ros.org/question/248178/can-i-set-initial-joint-positions-in-gazebomoveit-via-configuration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can set the environment variable in commandline, e.g.:

```
ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE="-y 2" roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch^C
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inani47](https://answers.ros.org/users/32531/inani47/) on 2018-04-14**:
is there a way to add this to my launch file for turtlebot?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can create your own launch file to spawn the robot. For example:

```
<!-- spawn_robot.launch -->
<launch>
  <!-- Robot pose -->
  <arg name="x" default="0"/>
  <arg name="y" default="0"/>
  <arg name="z" default="0"/>
  <arg name="roll" default="0"/>
  <arg name="pitch" default="0"/>
  <arg name="yaw" default="0"/>

  <param name="robot_description"
         command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find myrobot_description)/urdf/myrobot.urdf.xacro"/>
  <node name="spawn_robot" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model"
        args="-urdf -param robot_description -model myrobot
              -x $(arg x) -y $(arg y) -z $(arg z)
              -R $(arg roll) -P $(arg pitch) -Y $(arg yaw)"/>
</launch>
```

Then you change `<include file="$(find pr2_gazebo)/launch/pr2.launch"/>` to:

```
<include file="$(find myrobot_description)/launch/spawn_robot.launch">
  <arg name="x" value="1.0"/>
  <arg name="y" value="1.0"/>
</include>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 792 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 23

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-06**:
Thanks Jim, I like this approach, will consider adding these arguments/defaults to the pr2_no_controllers.launch.

**Comment by [Infraviored](https://answers.ros.org/users/134455/infraviored/) on 2023-01-17**:
Hey Jim,
Many thaks for providing this solution. Can you tell me how i apply this to a UR10 robot? I described my problem here:

https://answers.ros.org/question/411488/change-gazebo-default-robot-pose/